# Make paragraph bounce

Tags: javascript, css

I have a paragraph that in my language says:

START A
NEW PROJECT
WITH US

I'd like to make this paragraph bounce. What's my best option here if I am not too advanced at coding? The current code used is:

```
<p><a href="linkhere">START ET<br>
<h4>NYT PROJEKT</h4><br>
MED OS</a></p>
```

By bounce I basically just mean some way of making the guy browsing the website notice it. There is stuff above and below it, so by it making some sort of a move it'd drag attention.

I know how to give the paragraph an ID, so for test purposes let's just assume the

has the ID paragraphbounce.

This is the CSS I tried.

```html
@keyframes tada {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  10%, 20% {
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }

  40%, 60%, 80% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.paragraphbounce {
  animation-name: tada;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) can help you

Comment: Code attempt added, sorry. Thank you Mosh, I tried following that guide earlier.

Comment: Bouncing text is a bad idea if your user base may contain people with visual difficulties (it can induce nausea, headaches, etc.), and it also looks pretty tacky IMO. You would be better off creating contrast through the use of different text sizes and weights, and/or using different typefaces.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to ask something different once you have fixed the initial problem. It invalidates any answers given and others with similar queries won't be able to gain help from your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ss9tvwje/

```
/* The animation code */
@keyframes example {
    0% {top:15px}
    33% {top:30px}
    66% {top:40px}
    100% {top:15px}
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
div.bounce {
    animation: example 4s infinite;
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
}
```

From the sounds of it you want to use CSS animation like in the (simple) example above.

Comment: I am trying to make the following effect https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ ( bounce ) but the code I copy does not seem to cut it, I must be messing it up. I am looking to add it to my <p> tag with the iD paragraphbounce. I have added my code attempt